# What is the accepted way to store linked data in NoSQL?

Tags: nosql

I want to store articles in NoSQL. Each article has a title, summary and sections. Thats no big deal to do. I would also like to tag articles, again easy to do. I also want to store information about tags besides the name, say a definition and an icon. I'm don't want to store the extra tag information each time a tag is used. This leaves me with putting the extra information in a separate collection. So whats the accepted way to go about this in NoSQL? Both storing and retrieving?

For example in SQL I would have a article, tags and a article_tags table and I could do something like `SELECT * FROM article_tags INNER JOIN tags on tags.id=article_tags.tag_id WHERE article_tags.art_id=##`

In NoSQL I'm thinking something like:

```
article = {
  title    : 'The article',
  tags     : ['tag1', 'tag2', ... ],
  summary  : 'paragraph summary',
  sections : ['section 1', 'section 2', ... ]
}
tags = {
  tag        : 'tag1',
  definition : 'The meaning of the tag',
  icon       : 'URL'
}
```

But as far as I know there is no such equivalent to a JOIN in NoSQL, so I would have to make a separate call for each tag to lookup its info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a document and graph NoSQL database like [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/).

There is a [tutorial explaining OrientDB's document and graph model](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Tutorial%3a-Document-and-graph-model).

Answer (score -2):

You would have to make a separate call - depending on which NoSQL solution you're using. You would have to write your application in such a way that most efficiently leverages the strengths of the NoSQL solution.

I'm most familiar with Redis and Python so in your example I'd probably do something like this structure:

```
articles = {        
                title: 'The article.',
                tags     : ['tag1','tag2','tag3'],
                summary  : 'paragraph summary',
                sections : ['section 1', 'section 2', ... ]
           }
```

and then for retrieval (with appropriate Python client setup, etc)

```
... client setup and connection stuff
key = 'article_id_value'
data = rclient.hget('articles',key)
tags = data['tags']
...
```

The goal of NoSQL is speed, not necessarily relations, ACID, or removing the potential for update anomalies. This last one is why there is less of an emphasis on normalization and not storing data in multiple locations. However, if you *reallyreallyreallyreallyreally* wanted to normalize, you could do something like:

```
articles = {        
                title: 'The article.',
                tags     : [tag_key,tag_key,tag_key ],
                summary  : 'paragraph summary',
                sections : ['section 1', 'section 2', ... ]
           }


tags = {
  tag        : 'tag1',
  definition : 'The meaning of the tag',
  icon       : 'URL'
}
```

and then you'd retrieve like:

```
... client setup and connection stuff
key = 'article_id_value'
data = rclient.hget('articles',key)
tags = data['tags']
tagnames = []
for tag in tags:
    tagnames.append(rclient.hget('tags',tag))
data['tagnames'] = tagnames
...
```

Please note - I'm doing this from memory while looking at the Python and Redis docs. I'm a SQL Server DBA so I naturally tend to lean toward relational data modeling.

Comment: @TheOptimusPrimus ... thanks for the revenge downvote except i didnt downvote you ... so enjoy your lonely bitterness